# Call function for one UICollectionViewCell only

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have got custom `UICollectionViewCell` and here is `cellForItemAt:` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post{
        //determine which constraint to call
        if(CurrentPost.PostText != nil){
            if(CurrentPost.PostImage != nil){
                cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
                cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithText()
            }else{
                cell.postImage.image = nil
                cell.cellConstraintsWithoutImageWithText()
            }
        }else{
            cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
            cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithoutText()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I want to call `constraint` function based on absence or presence of `UIImage`, but when one function gets called it stays so all the cells get messed up because one cell is being re-used when scrolling back up.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line after cell initialization,

```
cell.removeConstraints(cell.constraints)
```

So will look like this,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.removeConstraints(cell.constraints)

    if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post{
        //determine which constraint to call
        if(CurrentPost.PostText != nil){
            if(CurrentPost.PostImage != nil){
                cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
                cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithText()
            }else{
                cell.postImage.image = nil
                cell.cellConstraintsWithoutImageWithText()
            }
        }else{
            cell.postImage.image = CurrentPost.PostImage
            cell.cellConstraintsWithImageWithoutText()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! Spent 5 hours looking for one line of code...

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Oh my goodness!! Many thanks Zaid!! You are a life saver. I spent more than 2 days for this. Thanks @sakoaskoaso for the question. :P upvotes for both.

Answer (score 3):

In the `prepareForReuse` method of your `PostCell` class you need back your constraint to original state

something like this

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.yourConstraint.constant = originalValue //this is an example
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: it says that `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.I don't thinik prepareForReuse is for uicollectionviewcells

Comment: @sakoaskoaso yes exist, check again I have done this in several projects, something must be wrong with your PostCell class, can you post?

Comment: Wait should i call this in PostCell or where UIcollectionview itself is?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso in your PostCell, as i said in my answer please check, this is the correct way to do this

Comment: What about the answer above by Zaid?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso is matter of preference, i think the cell responsability is handle how his data is presented, but i think that his answer fit better for your proposes, anyway you can try and check that my answer also works